# Find added files in index before an initial commit is made

Tags: git, addition, stage

I am writing a script that finds all files that are added to the stage. I have only come up with solutions that work when there is already a initial commit (ie using git diff-index --name-status HEAD). But no solution that works when there is no HEAD.

ie:

```
% git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/jocke/dev/agical/test/.git/

% cat >> test
content
^C
% git add --all    
% git st
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   test
#

% git diff-index --name-status HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

git status seems to be able to figure out what needs to be added. There is probably some plumbing that I could use but I can't seem to find it. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure it answers your question, but have a look at the option `-N` of `git add`

Comment: Does not look like what I am after. I want to be able to find "A   added_file.txt" in any repository including repositories without an initial commit.
I have found how to do the diff now when I know there is no initial commit:

    git diff-index --name-status `git hash-object -t tree /dev/null` 

But don't know yet how to determine if there is an inititial commit or not...

Comment: Well, `git rev-parse HEAD` will error out if there isn't one, for instance.

Comment: Thanks, that may be the best way to do it

Answer (score 1):

All you want is:

```
git diff --cached --name-status
```

And works even if there is no initial commit.

Or you want to do:

```
git status --porcelain
```

Comment: results:

   $ git diff --cached --name-status
   fatal: No HEAD commit to compare with (yet)
   
   $ git status --porcelain
   A  hepp`

--porcelain does not work with git 1.6.5 but that may be something I can live with. When was --porcelain introduced?

Comment: @johlrogge - The first command works for me. Maybe even that has changed. 1.6.5 is pretty old. Update to 1.7+

Comment: The first command does not work in: git version 1.7.4.msysgit.0

(tried it at work, 1.6.5 is what I happened to have on my laptop at home. Time to update that one :))

Comment: @johlrogge - Works for me on 1.7.6. Too sleepy to see when it was changed. But either should work on latest git.